# how to generate a symmetric sequence (same amount of elements of each part) between 0 and 1 in c?

Tags: c

I have a double-chained list with descriptor of which the information in each node is a soccer team (also a structured type, with name, origin and an identification number). I have to separate the total teams in two groups randomly, but keeping an equal amount in each (except if the amount is odd).

Comment: Apart from not currently sporting any code attempting this (at least none posted to *this* question), what, exactly, is the problem you're experiencing? And unrelated, netbeans is a development UI. That tag has no business being in this question.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, why not 1) Create an array and copy a pointer to each team into it, 2) Create two new, empty lists, 3) Initialize a random number generator, 4) Copy a random element from the array into one list, then the other. 5) null that array element after you copy it.  6) If the random number is a "null;" element, then call "rand()" again.

Comment: If you know number of teams (assume you do), Create 2 empty lists called say left and right.  Roll a random number from 0 to num-teams-1.  Every odd time, through, put into left, even time into right.  Once a team is moved, decrease num_teams by 1 and repeat until list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Select one team at random and assign it to group 1.  Then pick another team at random and assign to group 2.

Repeat until all teams have been assigned to a group.

Comment: Q: How do you "pick a team at random" from a doubly-linked list?  Not "criticizing" ... just asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over your list, compute a hash value for each item (which should almost be random), and sort the item against the hash value modulo the number of category you like to have (here is 2). It seems to me that could make the job.